# React + typescript using CDN script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im using reactjs with typescript.
Im trying to use `cdn` script inside a component.

`index.html and .tsx component`

```js
// .tsx file
const handleScript = () => {
  // property 'someScript' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
  window.someScript()
  // or with same error
  someScript()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script defer src="https://some.script.org/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding this at the top of the .tsx file: `/* global someScript */` (untested)

Comment: tried `/* global someScript */` and `declare global someScript`, error not resolving

Answer (score 2):

#### Solve

just add:

```js
declare global {
    interface Window { someScript: any }
}
```